# How to edit Wi-Fi router DHCP clients name?

Tags: router, wireless-router, dhcp

I Have a TP-Link router where 6 or 7 devices are connected. But these devices names are shown like this (android-8e1336e02e213bef). I want to edit their names just to identify who is connected through my router. But there is no option in web-ui where I can edit their hostname. Is it possible to edit their hostname from My PC? If then, How?

[image: These Devices are connected through my router. I want to edit their hostname.]

Answer (score 1):

The router just reports the name that each device gives it when they connect. You have to change the device's name in the device's operating system itself. For instance, in Windows 10, you would go to Settings > System > About, and then click the "Change Name"
button on the resulting page. When installing an OS, one is usually asked to set a hostname for the machine, and if that is ignored, some default name is given.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the host names from the PC.

For android devices, go to Settings > About your phone > Edit the hostname there.

For windows computers/laptops, @kreemoweet has shown a way. Just you have to do a restart after completing the steps.

The router admin page shows the friendly host names of the DHCP clients (devices connected).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. My phone has its name correctly set in Settings > About, but my router still displays it as "Unknown" in the devices list.

Answer (score 0):

If  u are using an iphone with IOS 16.xxx:

1. In settings->WiFi, select your network name.
2. Select the ‘i’ (information) button for that network name.
3. Change the privacy button to off.
4. The device name in the General->about field will display
   only for that network.
5. Do that for every IOS device on the network.